# Attempting to implement FIREBASE react-native-firebase/app with Expo

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, expo

I'm trying to use `@react-native-firebase/app` and `@react-native-firebase/auth` with my expo app, I have created all my app, and I will start the implementation with firebase now, although when I attempt to make the auth, it keeps returning me this error:

```
Error: Requiring module "node_modules/@react-native-firebase/auth/lib/index.js", which threw an exception: Invariant Violation: Native module cannot be null.
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:104:6 in reportException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/ExceptionsManager.js:171:19 in handleException
at node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Core/setUpErrorHandling.js:24:6 in handleError
at node_modules/expo-error-recovery/build/ErrorRecovery.fx.js:12:21 in ErrorUtils.setGlobalHandler$argument_0
```

This is how I have setup the Firebase data

app.json:

```
{
  "expo": {
    "name": "gofinances",
    "slug": "gofinances",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "assetBundlePatterns": [
      "**/*"
    ],
        "ios": {
      "googleServicesFile": "./ios/GoogleService-Info.plist"
    },
        "plugins": [
      "@react-native-firebase/app",
            "@react-native-firebase/auth"
    ]
  },
  "name": "gofinances"
}
```

Inside of `ios/gofinances/AppDelegate.m` I have added:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    [FIRApp configure]; // ADDED THIS LINE
    #if defined(FB_SONARKIT_ENABLED) && __has_include(<FlipperKit/FlipperClient.h>)
        InitializeFlipper(application);
    #endif
  
  self.moduleRegistryAdapter = [[UMModuleRegistryAdapter alloc] initWithModuleRegistryProvider:[[UMModuleRegistryProvider alloc] init]];
  self.launchOptions = launchOptions;
  self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[UIScreen mainScreen].bounds];
  #ifdef DEBUG
    [self initializeReactNativeApp];
  #else
    EXUpdatesAppController *controller = [EXUpdatesAppController sharedInstance];
    controller.delegate = self;
    [controller startAndShowLaunchScreen:self.window];
  #endif

  [super application:application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];

  return YES;
}
```

My function with makes that error get called is:

```
    function handleLogin(form: LoginProps) {
        setIsLoading(true);

        auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(form.email, form.password);

        setIsLoading(false);
    }
```

This is My IOS folder:
[image]

Image of the error:
[image]

Comment: You expo ejected right?

Comment: It threw an exception, I have added an image

Comment: Well you cant use `@react-native-firebase/app` in expo so you have to expo-eject. However you can `expo install firebase` and use expo's firebase library more here  (https://docs.expo.dev/guides/using-firebase/)

Comment: If I expo eject will it work? or I have to make another configuration? Will I still be able to install with `expo install`?

Comment: So yes if you want to use `@react-native-firebase/app` you must `expo-eject`. Yes you can still `expo install` if you expo-eject for many of the libraries but they will need more configuration steps then if you were just in an expo project. So `expo install` all the expo libraries you want, then expo-eject, then you can use `@react-native-firebase/app`.

Comment: When you `expo-eject` and download libraries read  very carefully through all the instructions of downloading it. Or you will run into errors

Comment: I think I have ran expo eject already, it ejects IOS and ANDROID folder right?

Comment: Yeah you have based on your image

Comment: You most likely haven't followed all the steps as you should when downloading `@react-native-firebase/app` it can be very tedious. Re read through them and make sure you did everything right.

Comment: Have you done this `cd ios/` `pod install --repo-update` after you added the `[FIRApp configure];`

Comment: Yep I have done so! Is the GoogleService in the right place?

Comment: (https://rnfirebase.io/) According to this it is not

Comment: I think that when I ran the `pod install --repo-update` it removed from that folder

Answer (score 0):

I believe you missed these steps in the documentation regarding your `GoogleService-Info.plist` (https://rnfirebase.io/). Your not suppose to add the `GoogleService-Info.plist` to your app.json but to your xcode project for ios.

Read below and visit the website I linked

````
1) Download the GoogleService-Info.plist file.

2) Using Xcode, open the projects /ios/{projectName}.xcodeproj file (or /ios/{projectName}.xcworkspace if using Pods).

3) Right click on the project name and "Add files" to the project, as 

4) Download the GoogleService-Info.plist file.

5) Using Xcode, open the projects /ios/{projectName}.xcodeproj file (or /ios/{projectName}.xcworkspace if using Pods).

6) Right click on the project name and "Add files" to the project, as ```
````

Comment: Actually it wasn't that hahah, dammit

Comment: Did you do what I said above?

Comment: Yep, but the configurations is fine

Comment: Well if the error says anything about versions let me know. Else good luck